# Casting problem cant convert from void to float C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, casting

as i said  i get this horrible error i dont really know what to do anymore

```
 float n= xAxis[i].Normalize();
```

thats where i get the error and i get it cuz normalize is a void function this is it

```
void CVector::normalize()
{
 float len=Magnitude();
 this->x /= len;
 this->y /= len;  
}
```

i need normalize to stay as void tho i tried normal casting like this

```
float n= (float)xAxis[i].Normalize();
```

and it doesnt work also with static,dynamic cast,reinterpret,const cast and cant make it work any help would be really apreciated...
thank you >.<

Comment: What is it that you expect "n" to hold after your call to Normalize()? ;-) I guess you need to read this first -> http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A void function doesn't return anything, so there's nothing to assign to n.

You should return some value from normalize to assign it to n.

```
float CVector::normalize()
{
 float len=Magnitude();
 this->x /= len;
 this->y /= len;
 return 10.0;
}
```

Comment: thats what i thought oh well im just modifying it to float ty vm

Comment: If you are just updating class members, you may be able to look at those instead of returning anything.

Comment: yeah sadly the thing is im modifying another class :S lol ty i think it works fine like that it was just me being ambitious XD

Answer (score 0):

`Normalize` doesn't return a value as it has a void return type.  It changes an internal member.  So you have to access that member directly or an accessor that returns that member.

Answer (score 0):

The `Normalize()` method doesn't return anything, so you can't assign the return value to a variable. Probably `Normalize()` just modifies the object it is called on.